# Problem accessing the page while using puppeteer connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to scrape information from an existing chrome page for learning purposes, using the puppeteer library.
I have opened the chrome with debugging mode, received the ws url of the chrome page I am in, and connected successfully. Here is the connection code:

```
//open library
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
//connect to excisting open page
async function connectToChrome()
    {
        //Connect to excisting browser
        const wsChromeEndpointurl = 'ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/page/5D6126455A889AA7D17B66C10729F352';
        const browser = await puppeteer.connect
            ({
                  browserWSEndpoint: wsChromeEndpointurl
            });
```

The page which I have connected to is inside a url of a youtube video. My code's purpose is to find the amount of views of the video I am currently watching and log it to the console.
When I have used this code while opening a new browser it was very easy, but now that I have connected to an existing page I don't really understand what is going on. I am not exactly sure how to access the information that is in the page, in a normal browser open you just open a new page, go to url, and save it to a variation. But right now I have no idea how to scrape information from the page as it is already open. Here is my code:

```
//open library
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
//connect to excisting open page
async function connectToChrome()
    {
        //Connect to excisting browser
        const wsChromeEndpointurl = 'ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/page/5D6126455A889AA7D17B66C10729F352';
        const browser = await puppeteer.connect
            ({
                  browserWSEndpoint: wsChromeEndpointurl
            });
        const [el] = await browser.page.$x('//*[@id="count"]/yt-view-count-renderer/span[1]');
        const txt = await el.getProperty('textContent');
        const txtJson = await txt.jsonValue();
        console.log(txtJson);

    };

connectToChrome();
```

This code will return not understand the following line sentence, as it is undefined:

```
browser.page.$x
```

What would be the right syntax to access this element?

Answer (score 0):

`browser.page.$x` is not valid. You need to find the page in the array of pages of the browser

```js
const pages = await browser.pages();
const yourPage = pages.find(page => page.url() === 'someUrlToLookAt');
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. Just to clarify it, me connecting to the ws url of the page is not automatically putting me inside that page? it only puts me inside the browser?

Comment: Exactly, you can take a look at this issue https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/4579